# Finding significant changepoints using Segneigh method

Tags: r, statistical-significance, aic, change-point

I am analyzing changes in the data set in time as mentioned below. To find significant changepoints in time, I am using the 'changepoint package', cptmeanvar function, SegNeigh method, and AIC as the penalty. It gives a maximum of 129 changepoints and the number varies with different values of the Q parameter.

1. Is this method and penalty type suitable for the given data set?
2. I tried constructing an elbow plot to optimize the number of changepoints, however, it didn't work.
3. Are all changepoints thus obtained significant? Is there any other way (except the elbow plot) to narrow down the significant change points?

Data:

```
YEAR    JUN     JUL     AUG     SEP
1871    2223    3871    2856    2980
1872    2340    3210    2885    1958
1873    609     3843    2580    1714
1874    2722    3186    3362    2323
1875    1594    3344    2958    2413
1876    960     3222    2396    2391
1877    1054    1989    1871    1230
1878    735     2549    3045    2058
1879    1521    3666    3651    2622
1880    1810    3418    2679    1719
1881    2069    3237    3377    1306
1882    1812    3078    2983    1447
1883    2589    3294    1775    1685
1884    1784    2603    3016    2691
1885    2006    3214    3492    1699
1886    1940    3340    3033    2445
1887    1474    3124    3375    1736
1888    733     3808    4265    1985
1889    2309    3520    3232    1886
1890    2881    4386    2839    2287
1891    772     2053    4016    2881
1892    1704    3604    3465    1661
1893    2185    3472    2529    3258
1894    2287    3613    3676    2120
1895    2685    3200    2999    1541
1896    2296    3090    3220    1026
1897    1703    3033    3498    1914
1898    1540    2989    3588    2764
1899    2519    4120    2308    964
1900    1537    2633    3076    3134
1901    439     2423    3506    1799
1902    688     3943    2370    2463
1903    1142    2047    3123    2165
1904    2356    3707    3345    1235
1905    414     3155    3005    2606
1906    1863    3304    2950    1861
1907    1679    2031    3640    1216
1908    1291    2931    3697    1251
1909    2748    3683    2502    1894
1910    1908    2789    3614    2367
1911    2487    1193    3377    3149
1912    883     3273    3335    1640
1913    2511    2788    2945    1354
1914    1274    3725    3235    1814
1915    1178    2609    3208    2656
1916    2423    3053    3305    2203
1917    2112    3135    2671    2824
1918    2468    1498    3228    1527
1919    1950    3411    3460    1845
1920    1221    4991    2135    1550
1921    1769    2736    3798    2675
1922    2137    4199    3708    2875
1923    901     2760    3626    2051
1924    791     3802    2700    2897
1925    2145    4230    2981    1849
1926    381     3546    3819    2303
1927    1355    3388    3311    1510
1928    1665    3721    1795    1231
1929    1523    3699    3582    1053
1930    1157    3891    2669    2401
1931    691     3106    3148    2947
1932    844     2910    2575    2277
1933    2224    3068    3425    2070
1934    1668    3349    3300    2277
1935    926     3407    3105    2447
1936    3099    4369    3319    2749
1937    1425    2973    3149    1879
1938    2521    3218    3271    1849
1939    1872    3337    2890    2418
1940    1470    3671    3667    1288
1941    2029    2271    3160    1665
1942    1426    3632    3612    2848
1943    1227    3429    4451    2427
1944    1304    3613    3411    1491
1945    1053    2987    2592    2992
1946    1681    3621    3018    1757
1947    1269    3522    2868    2157
1948    1328    3665    3642    2421
1949    1121    3405    3549    2415
1950    2223    3012    3303    1529
1951    1382    2625    2669    1851
1952    2204    2490    3461    2124
1953    1840    3831    3560    2416
1954    1162    2704    2659    2363
1955    1656    3368    3132    2431
1956    2302    3104    3308    2889
1957    950     3275    3214    1979
1958    821     3162    3399    2578
1959    1227    2706    3006    1703
1960    1133    3536    3755    2028
1961    1798    3048    3754    2341
1962    1161    2853    3146    2418
1963    1480    2891    3292    2631
1964    1085    4064    2863    2394
1965    649     2961    2315    1993
1966    2037    2191    2612    940
1967    1039    2814    4169    2098
1968    1643    3092    2590    1417
1969    1157    3751    3120    2269
1970    1878    2420    2701    2667
1971    2531    3182    3967    1880
1972    697     2315    2774    2303
1973    1396    3106    3166    2274
1974    798     3212    2871    1537
1975    1904    3435    2821    2218
1976    945     2947    3441    2524
1977    1364    3965    2732    1783
1978    1957    2894    3280    2191
1979    1246    2907    1511    941
1980    2207    4130    3041    2369
1981    1195    3869    2600    2293
1982    1452    1992    3807    1770
1983    1233    2848    2823    2919
1984    2981    3482    3452    1761
1985    1114    3311    2938    2837
1986    1833    3389    2531    1493
1987    733     3102    2813    2220
1988    1874    3109    3327    1588
1989    2089    3122    2767    2211
1990    1672    3939    2734    2252
1991    1434    2462    4138    1995
1992    1234    2935    3071    1451
1993    1819    2026    2572    3031
1994    1878    3507    3511    2075
1995    1160    2546    3183    2477
1996    1884    2155    3381    1536
1997    1696    3402    3332    1939
1998    1012    3113    3175    2013
1999    1946    3106    2896    2404
2000    2249    2613    2268    2077
2001    2804    3696    2139    1497
2002    1040    1486    2498    2193
2003    1582    2945    2980    2747
2004    1834    2476    2713    1410
2005    1125    3313    2204    2141
2006    1765    3779    3275    1961
2007    1807    3173    3077    2630
2008    3195    3932    3376    2021
2009    665     3184    2637    1930
2010    837     2751    2350    2268
2011    2332    2230    3089    2629
2012    845     3093    3170    2073
2013    2743    2697    2584    1490
2014    826     3143    2452    1686
2015    1544    2622    2222    1036
2016    1185    3290    2539    2156
```

My code:

```
library(changepoint)
library(TSstudio)
#tseries is the time series of the data provided
ts.seg=cpt.meanvar(tseries,method="SegNeigh",Q=130, penalty='AIC')
ts.seg
cpts(ts.seg)
plot(ts.seg)
plot(ts.seg,diagnostic=TRUE)
```

Comment: This video gives a very good overview of the changepoint package. It will answer your questions.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WelmlZK5G2Y&list=WL&index=92